Wrong result in Eigen when returning a expression from within a lambda
I'm trying to use the body of this function in a lambda:
Vector3d fun(Vector3d const& point) {
    Vector3d const b{ 0., 0., 30. };
    return b + point.normalized();
}

but when the result is not explicitly evaluated before returning, either with
return (b + point.normalized()).eval();

or
Vector3d ret = b + point.normalized();
return ret;

the result is wrong for a lambda like
auto lamb = [](Vector3d const& point) {
    Vector3d const b{ 0., 0., 30. };
    return b + point.normalized();
    };

and i don't understand why.
The docs note that returning objects by value is ok and i'm not sure if and how to apply what's noted here.
I'm trying to understand why with this example body a lambda needs the explicit eval before return but an ordinary free function doesn't.
Short Demo
Long Demo
Code of the short demo:
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using Vector3d = Eigen::Vector3d;

Vector3d fun(Vector3d const& point) {
    Vector3d const b{ 0., 0., 30. };
    return b + point.normalized();
}

int main()
{
    auto lamb = [](Vector3d const& point) {
        Vector3d const b{ 0., 0., 30. };
        return b + point.normalized();
        //Vector3d ret = b + point.normalized(); return ret;
        };

    Vector3d const point{ 1., 2., 3. };

    Vector3d const resultl = lamb(point);
    std::cout << resultl.x() << " / " << resultl.y() << " / " << resultl.z() << "\n";

    Vector3d const resultf = fun(point);
    std::cout << resultf.x() << " / " << resultf.y() << " / " << resultf.z() << "\n";
}


https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html you may check the section: C++11 and the auto keyword.

@rafix07 That's the link i posted. I just don't understand which part of it explains the difference between free and lambda functions.

the difference is that you deduce the return type of the lambda via auto

return b + point.normalized(); returns an Eigen expression type that stores references to the two operands.
In your free function, your return type is Vector3d which results in the expression being evaluated inside the function and then returning the result.
In the lambda, the return type is auto deduced and as such, you're returning the Eigen expression itself. Then, then b and point go out of scope and their references inside the returned expression become dangling.
This is fixed by evaluating the Eigen expression before returning, either by manually assigning or casting it to a Vector3d or by explicitly setting the return type of the lambda:
auto lamb = [](Vector3d const& point) -> Vector3d {
    Vector3d const b{ 0., 0., 30. };
    return b + point.normalized();
    //Vector3d ret = b + point.normalized(); return ret;
    };

Live Demo

@463035818_is_not_an_ai good idea, done

Ok. I'm an idiot and thought i could reproduce my actual problem which is with a std::function with a lambda but missed the explicit return type. I'll accept your answer to not have moving goal posts but can you please have a look at the actual question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79093880/wrong-result-in-eigen-when-returning-a-expression-from-within-a-stdfunction

Just to clarify your confusion about situation where you assign your lambda to std::function<Vector3d(Vector3d const&)>. Consider simplified scenario:
int main() {
    std::function<int()> fun = []() -> const int& {
        int result{69};
        return result;
    };
    std::cout << fun() << std::endl;
}

The code above has Undefined Behavior, because lambda is returning a dangling reference (here compiler would warn you about it, but not in the case of Eigen types) to local variable. The type of std::function doesn't change that fact, because std::function is a wrapper around your callable - in this case a lambda that returns const int&. So, inside operator() lambda is called, returns dangling reference, which is used to create an object of type int, which operator() returns by value.
The same happens with
// ExpressionObject -> I made it up, I don't know how it is actually called inside Eigen
std::function<Vector3d()> = []() -> Eigen::ExpressionObject { /*impl*/ };


This clarifies my wrong reasoning perfectly.
